# Android view enum

Tags: java, android, enums

In Android I want to make a enum with views (let's say with EditTexts).
I thought to initialize an EditText with `findViewById(R.id.something)`, you have to do that in a activity-class or you need a instance of this class.

So how can I initialize the EditTexts in a enum or can I set the Views from the main-class?

I thought about something like this, but it won't work:

```
enum Edits {
    one(/* what to write here */), two(/* what to write here */);

    private EditText editText;

    Edits(EditText editText){
        this.editText = editText;
    }

    EditText getEditText(){
        return this.editText;
    }

    void setEditText(EditText editText){ // Maybe something like this?
        this.editText = editText;
    }
}
```

So, how would you do that?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I thought it would be more comfortable as an list, because I can store more than one information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempting to store a reference to an `EditText`, or any `View` for that matter in an enum really isn't going to work.

In Java, an enum is essentially a singleton, and as you point out, a `View` is coupled to its `Context`, which would be its Activity or Fragment.  So it really doesn't make sense to have an object that is long lived (your enum) reference objects that are extremely short lived (your `EditText`).

As an alternative, you could have your enum store the ID of your `View` (example, `R.id.myEditText`), and then when you want to retrieve the actual instance, pass in your Activity or Fragment and call `findViewById()` to get the actual instance.

**Example:**

```
enum Edits {
    one(R.id.field1), two(R.id.field2);

    private int editTextId;

    Edits(int editTextId) {
        this.editTextId = editTextId;
    }

    EditText getEditText(Activity activity){
        return (EditText)activity.findViewById(editTextId);
    }
}
```